# What is the Dask equivalent of the Pandas .filter() attribute?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I am trying to make sub-DataFrames from a larger DataFrame in Dask. I realize that a lot of the tools found in Pandas used to manipulate DataFrames are present in Dask, however the devs are very transparent about what is not.

One such tool is the `df.filter()` attribute for DataFrames. I have code that looks like this:

```
comp2phys = df.filter(FOI[1:], axis=1)
```

where `df` is a DataFrame and `FOI` is a list containing the "fieldnames of interest".

I get this error when I try to filter the dataframe (as I explained above, it is not a tool in Dask)

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Is there a tool in Dask that will allow me to do this?
Thanks!

**EDIT**

As @ayhan pointed out, this equivalent to `df[FOI[1:]]`

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to `df[FOI[1:]]` (which should work on dask dataframes as well)?

Comment: I facepalmed after posting this question because I realized that as well. Thank you for pointing that out Rafael.

Comment: (you may want to put that as an answer, so that this question doesn't appear unanswered)

Comment: @mdurant are you planning to implement `filter` at some point?

Answer (score 1):

As @ayhan pointed out, this equivalent to `df[FOI[1:]]`